# Protected template member functions in a template class

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose we have

```
template<typename T>
class Base
{
    ...

    protected:

        template<typename U>
        void compute(U x);

    ...
};
```

Now I want to call this method from a derived class. With non-template member functions I would normally use `using ...` declaration or access members with `this->...`. However, it's not clear how to access template members:

```
template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base<T>
{
    // what's the correct syntax for
    // using ... template ... Base<T>::compute<U> ... ?

    ...

    void computeFloat()
    {
        float x = ...;
        compute<float>(x);
    }

    void computeDouble()
    {
        double x = ...;
        compute<double>(x);
    }

    ...
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even easier. You can write:

```
void computeFloat() {
    float x = .1;
    this->compute(x);
}
```

Type is auto-deduced.

**EDIT**

For the general case, when the type cannot be deduced, you can use either:

```
Base<T>::template compute<float>();
```

Or:

```
this->template compute<float>();
```

For the examples I've used a `compute` function with no parameter.

Comment: Thanks, but what about a general case when it cannot be auto-deduced? I gave a toy example and, unfortunately, in my case it doesn't deduce the template parameter.